# How to access the attributes from eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

**I have the following relationship,**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Products', 'id','product_id');
}
```

**and**

```
public function warehouse1StockSummary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Warehouse1StockSummaries', 'id', 'product_codeid');
}
```

**and here's how I call the two model**

```
 $wh1Summaries=Warehouse1StockSummaries::with('product');
```

they are working because I was able to get their info if i do this

```
if($request->type=='qty_in'){
    $wh1Summaries->where('qty_in','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
}
```

my foreach is also able to get them by doing this

```
foreach ($wh1Summaries as $wh1Summary) {
    $data[]=array(
        'product_code'=>$wh1Summary->product->product_code,
        'name'=>$wh1Summary->product->name,
        'qty_in'=>$wh1Summary->qty_in,
        'id'=>$wh1Summary->product->id
    );
}
```

My problem is if i try to call the attributes from product like this

```
    if($request->type=='product_code'){
        $wh1Summaries->product->where('product_code','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    }
```

I get empty.

here is my function:

```
public function transferResponse(Request $request){
    $query = $request->get('term','');
    $wh1Summaries=Warehouse1StockSummaries::with('product');

    if($request->type=='product_code'){
        $wh1Summaries->product->where('product_code','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    }

    if($request->type=='product_name'){
        $wh1Summaries->product->where('name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    }

    if($request->type=='qty_in'){
        $wh1Summaries->where('qty_in','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    }

    if($request->type=='product_id'){
        $wh1Summaries->product->where('id','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    }

    $wh1Summaries=$wh1Summaries->get();        
    $data=array();
    foreach ($wh1Summaries as $wh1Summary) {
        $data[]=array(
            'product_code'=>$wh1Summary->product->product_code,
            'name'=>$wh1Summary->product->name,
            'qty_in'=>$wh1Summary->qty_in,
            'id'=>$wh1Summary->product->id
        );
    }
    if(count($data))
        return $data;
    else
        return [
            'product_code'=>'',
            'name'=>'',
            'qty_in'=>'',
            'id'=>''
        ];
}
```

[image]

What is the proper way of accessing the attributes from my product model?

I am using that script to my autocomplete form. please advise thanks in advance!

Comment: If a product attribute is supplied are you wanting to only get the summaries that has a product with those details?

Comment: Hi @RossWilson its you again hahaha. sorry I am not quite sure if I get your question correctly, but i think yes, let say 4 fields right? the product_code, name, qty_in and product_id. if the product code is supplied, basically the other fields will automatically get their appropriate details. but as of now the only working field is the qty_in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to get results by querying a relationship you can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) e.g.

```
$wh1Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
    $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
});
```

---

Also, when using `get()` or `all()` with Eloquent it'll return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods). This will allow you to using methods like [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) which will save you having to use temp variables and foreach loops.

---

This will mean your controller would look something like:

```
public function transferResponse(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('term', '');
    $wh1Summaries = Warehouse1StockSummaries::with('product');

    if ($request->type == 'product_code') {
        $wh1Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        });
    }

    if ($request->type == 'product_name') {
        $wh1Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        });
    }

    if ($request->type == 'qty_in') {
        $wh1Summaries->where('qty_in', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    }

    if ($request->type == 'product_id') {
        $wh1Summaries->product->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    }

    $data = $wh1Summaries->get()->map(function ($wh1Summary) {
        return [
            'product_code' => $wh1Summary->product->product_code,
            'name'         => $wh1Summary->product->name,
            'qty_in'       => $wh1Summary->qty_in,
            'id'           => $wh1Summary->product->id,
        ];
    });

    if ($data->isNotEmpty()) {
        return $data;
    }

    return [
        'product_code' => '',
        'name'         => '',
        'qty_in'       => '',
        'id'           => '',
    ];
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks @RossWilson! the whereHas works. I actually read the wherHas a while ago I just don't know how to practically use it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lito Glad I could help. Are you cool with how `whereHas` works now?

Comment: yes @RossWilson whereHas works great :) you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Your call should be:

```
$wh1Summaries = Warehouse1StockSummaries::with(['product' => function($q) {
    $q->where('product_code','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
}]);
```

The query builder's `->where()` should not be used on the `product` as essentially you are querying against the summaries and not the product.

As the `::with()` clause is conditional to on `$request->type == product_name`, you can use `newQuery()` to start a new eloquent query, then set which `->with()` clause to use:

```
$wh1Summaries = Warehouse1StockSummaries::newQuery();

if($request->type == 'product_name'){
    $wh1Summaries = $wh1Summaries->with(['product' => function($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('product_code','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    }]);
} else {
    $wh1Summaries = $wh1Summaries->with('product');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thisiskelvin I'll try to adopt your answer

Comment: If you want to query against summaries that have products with certain types, use @ross-wilson answer